# Как задать метод для функции вебдрайвера

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
def multi_work(url):
    for URL in url:
        driver_head.get(url=url)
        if driver_head.find_element("/html/body/div[6]/div/section/div/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button/div/div/span").text:
            print(driver_head.current_url)
        else:
            continue
```

1. Хочу запустить веб драйвер, по ссылке из списка.
2. Если веб драйвер **видит** по этой ссылке нужный мне элемент с нужным текстом, то он копирует ссылку этой страницы и еще одну ссылку с этой страницы и закидывает в бд, а если он **не видит**, элемент с нужным текстом, то он просто пропускает эту сессию веб драйвера.

**Вопрос:** Какой метод применяется к этой функции, которая будет пропускать сессию веб драйвера, если она не будет находить нужный элемент с текстом?

Answer (score 0):

Тут стоит уточнить, что вы подразумеваете под "***скипать***" сессию?

Я думаю, что в случае не нахождения элемента, просто вызывайте **continue** внутри цикла по списку из ссылок. Соответственно:

```
driver.get(link)
```

Должно хватить что бы перейти на следущую страницу.

Если вам нужно полностью убить driver(а нужно ли?). То можно вызвать:

```
driver.close()
```

Всё же, было бы не плохо. Если вы предоставите хоть немного кода и пояснений, что именно вы хотите от драйвера.

Comment: multiprocessing

К примеру запускается 2 сессии браузера. Первая сессия работает с ссылкой на стр, которой есть нужная информация, вторая на которой нет. 

Так вот с первой надо вытащить инфу, а вторую сессию просто закрыть и запустить другую по списку ссылку для проверки.

Если нет информации, просто запустить процесс с новой ссылкой!

Comment: Вам не кажется что это весьма кривая архитектура для такой задачи? Может быть, в таком случае лучше парсить через requests вместе с bs4? В таком случае вы сможете создать сколько угодно запросов и без ожидания response создавать новые запросы (threading) (Конечно стоит будет подумать о семафоре для потоков, что бы ресурс не забанил). Внутри функции для потоков, описать логику проверки элементов и записи в бд.

Comment: Я не совсем хорошо в этом разбираюсь но надеюсь, что в бедующем я исправлю всю кривизну своего проекта. Сейчас хотелось бы понять как сделать хотя бы это. 

Если нет информации на ссылке, просто запустить процесс с новой ссылкой

Comment: Приведите примеры кода, и какой либо из идентификаторов элемента на странице - который надо найти.